# File association to javaws does not work

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association

This is on Windows 10 platform. We associate .jsp files to 'javaws' program from under java installation. This used to work fine, with javaws launched to process the contents of the JSP file.  This is now broken for some users while it works OK for others. So it is specific to users' machines.

If the JSP files are associated with another program like 'notepad', it works fine with notepad launched displaying the contents of the JSP file. So it would appear it is just the javaws.  It is not just JSP files, it does not work with any other file types.

The program launches fine from the command line

```
javaws test.jsp
```

It is just that the program does not launch via file association even when the association itself seems to be successful.  Reinstalling Java does not help.

What could be causing this?  Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: so what is jsp associated with on a working PC? can you not just change the association on the broken systems back to the prior executable, instead of notepad?

Comment: Can you verify if jawaws is running as 32- or 64-bit when launched from the command line? Task Manager > Details > Right-click > Open file location. Make sure you select this exact javaws executable when creating the association and try again.

Comment: @FrankThomas JSP is associated with javaws, the prior executable. It does not work. javaws will not launch  associated with any file type.

Comment: @FastEthernet - I have tried this a few times.  I only have 64 bit java installed. The association is to that.

Comment: did you copy all the arguments and start in configuration from one of the working stations to the one you are attempting to fix the association on? just a guess.

Comment: There are no arguments or configurations to be made. It is just that this one application (javaws) that would not launch based on file association. When clicked on the associated file, it should launch javaws before anything else. It does not do that.

Comment: What happens specifically would you associated the file extension within the executable in the 64-bit bin directory and select javaws.  I can confirm that, the association with Javaws, works absolutely so any problems are user specific. When you say it's broken what do you mean exactly?  Have you confirmed that the java environment is not erronously being set to a directory within System32?

Comment: The association of javaws has worked for us fine for a number of years. During the association, we navigate to the exact directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361\bin) and pick javaws. That is the only java installation. After the association, when the target file is clicked on, the cursor changes for a fraction of a second and nothing happens.  Typically, this should launch javaws.  The issue is user specific.